# Calculate quotient with Logarithm log2

Tags: javascript

I have to calculate a simple quotient:

```
log2(val1) / log2(val2)
```

I´ve tried to this with:

```
 var valueOne = Math.log2(val1);
 var valueTwo = Math.log2(val2);
 var quotient = valueOne / valueTwo;
```

Unfortunately,it do not work.As I found out, there are obviously browser compatibility problems with `Math.log2`

In Chrome, I get `*'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'*`

How can now calculate the quotient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this custom function

```
function log2(val) {
 return Math.log(val) / Math.LN2;
}

var valueOne = log2(val1);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aswLjv1/)

Comment: Note that `log2(Math.pow(2, 29)) !== 29`.

Comment: @Afsa: of course this is a quick fix that's useful if you're not concerned about accuracy, but it's something to be aware of if you need a precise result from `log2` or you are using `floor`/`ceil` on it.

Comment: @Qantas Using `Math.log2` gives you the same answer. If you need a more exact you need to use more sophisticated math.

Comment: @Qantas Well it is not reliable to use `==` when you are working with these kind of math operations. Perhaps we are using different browsers. You should use `Math.abs(x-y)<small`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Math.log2(x)` function can be computed as `Math.log(x) / Math.LN2;`. That can be derived from the nature of logarithms.

The `.log2()` function is a newcomer to the `Math` constructor, and not supported by all browsers.

Comment: You have a error in your code. `y = 2^x => x*ln(2) = ln(y) => x = ln(y)/ln(2) != ln(y)/ln(ln(2))`

Comment: @Afsa ?? huh?  OH wait I see what you mean; durr. Thanks.